# Calculating the voltage of zenerdiode

Tags: diodes, zener

We got an example exercise in which we need to calculate the voltage and current in certain places of a circuit with a zener diode with different input voltages (ranging from -10v to 10v). Most of the exercise is just applying ohm's law but I can't figure out how they get the voltage over the diode (the blue number).

These are parts of the solution
[image]
[image]
The orange number is the voltage of the source (-1,05V in the first case and 6v in the second). The green numbers are calculated using ohm's law and the voltage over the diode. But how they get the blue number (which is the voltage over the diode) is a complete mystery to me :/

NOTE: English isn't my first language so I might get certain terms wrong.

Comment: if 2k/3k * 6V = 4V then Zener is high impedance and has no effect. With negative Vin , the zener is now just a diode with -0.7 V drop

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I assume the 2k is the resistor on the right. Where do you get the 3k from?

Comment: @Ivaldir 3k is the total resistance of the two resistors in series (in the outermost voltage loop).

Comment: ohms law says the current goes through the sum of R in a loop, thus Vout=I*R(2k)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site and your English is very good.

When forward-biased (higher voltage on anode, lower voltage on cathode), a zener diode behaves just like a normal diode. It has a forward voltage drop of something like 0.7 V, with the exact voltage depending on the device, current through it, temperature and so on. Like an ordinary diode.

It's only when reverse-biased (higher voltage on cathode, lower voltage on anode) that the zener diode shows its special properties. All diodes have a reverse breakdown voltage, whereby they start conducting when a high-enough reverse voltage is applied. A zener diode is rated with a particular reverse breakdown voltage and is far more stable with it from device to device than other diodes.

And that's what you see in your circuit. When the voltage generator produces a negative voltage, the zener diode is forward biased and conducts like a normal diode. That's where your -0.7 V comes from. When the voltage generator produces a positive voltage, the zener has its rated voltage drop across it (ideal device here).

Note that a zener diode's rated reverse breakdown voltage is only a guide figure and they're not very precise or stable, as the current through them and temperature change. Always refer to a device's datasheet for details of how its reverse breakdown voltage behaves.

Comment: If the voltage generator produces a positive voltage and the zener has it's rated voltage drop of 5v how do they get 4v in the second example?

Comment: @Ivaldir Kirchhoff's Voltage Law.  Voltage drops and rises must be balanced for each loop of a parallel circuit.  The outermost loop consists of a 6V source, a 1k resistor, and a 2k resistor.  The resistors must, therefore, drop 2V and 4V, respectively.  So the voltage at the node immediately above the Zener must be 4V, which isn't enough to trigger breakdown in the diode.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In this example, the Zener is forward biased.  In that case it works just like a ordinary diode.  The special thing about Zeners is how they work under reverse bias.

The numbers here are a bit misleading, and are assuming idealized characteristic of the diode.  With Vin being -1.05 V, the resistors cause 700 mV to be applied across the diode.  Whoever created this diagram is apparently making the simplified assumption that the diode won't conduct forward current until 700 mV is applied to it.

That can be a valid approximation in some circuits, but I don't like it here due to the low currents.  Any real silicon diode is going to have some measurable current at 700 mV forward bias.  That current could easily be more than the small 350 µA flowing in this circuit.

Take this as a exercise to work thru voltage dividers and a very basic model of a diode, but not a good example of how a real diode would react in a real circuit.

[image]

In this example, the Zener is reverse biased, so it does its special Zener thing.  That special thing is to conduct when the reverse voltage reaches the Zener voltage.

In this case, the two resistors divide the 6 V source to make 4 V in reverse across the Zener.  However, the Zener voltage is 5 V.  Since the applied 4 V is less than the 5 V where the Zener would conduct, the Zener does not conduct.  Ideally, it acts like a open circuit.  That is why the current thru it is correctly shown as 0.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this DC_operating point solver.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUzYbm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>